# React native TextInput Component

Tags: react-native

I search it every day why it doesn't work properly.When I type anything onto TextInput's placeholder it starts with empty space.I want to start without space.I also tried `trim()` method.It wasn't helpful.How should I fix my error? Thanks in advance!

```
<TextInput value={this.state.key} onChangeText={(text) =>{this.setState({key:text.trim()}) ; console.warn('key: '+this.state.key)}}/>
```

Comment: Given code seems okay,Can u post the textinput wrapper also?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<TextInput
  value={this.state.key}
  keyboardType="default"
  onChangeText={key => this.setState({ key })}
/>;
```

**UPDATED ANSWER :**

```
_replaceSpace(str) {
    return str.replace(/\u0020/, '\u00a0')
  }

<TextInput
  style={{ textAlign: "right" }}
  value={this._replaceSpace(this.state.text)}
  onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text: text })}
/>;
```

Comment: It wasn't also helpful..((

Comment: Can anyone help me?